# Getting a list of all Layouts in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I have created 3 `print layouts` in QGIS3. Now I am trying to get a `list` of all `layouts` in the `LayoutManager` with `python`. This is how I am trying to do it(this code is executed in the python console of QGIS3):

```
>>> from qgis.core import QgsLayoutManager
>>> layoutmanager = QgsLayoutManager()
>>> layoutmanager.layouts()
>>> []
```

What I get is an empty `list`. So what am I missing? Do I have to save the `Layouts` in a special way? For those who don't understand what I mean with `layout`, in QGIS3 `Layout` is the new `Composer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code, you are creating a new instance of `QgsLayoutManager`. So, you don't get current list but an empty one.

You should retrieve the project instance with

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
```

From it, you can get the current `layoutManager` instance and deduce the layouts

```
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()

projectLayoutManager.layouts()
```

If you are not aware of it, the new Python API docs really helped https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html

Comment: Yeah thanks, I wasn't aware that there is a new Python API.

Comment: In fact, it's the docs for Python API who is new not the Python API itself (only some changes compared to QGIS 2.x version)