# Upgrading multiprint plugin to QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis-3

I'm trying to upgrade multiPrint plug in to QGIS3, but I'm newbie on python

My upgrade return an error like:

```
AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'activeComposers'

activeComposer no more exist in QGIS3
```

The code:

```
def populateComposerList(self):
    #called to populate field list for WHERE statement
    wdgt=self.dlg.composerList
    wdgt.clear()
    for cView in self.iface.activeComposers ():
        item=QListWidgetItem()
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        item.setText(cView.composerWindow().windowTitle())
        wdgt.addItem(item)
    wdgt.sortItems()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all Layouts in QGIS3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268572/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-layouts-in-qgis3)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! It's not unlikely that a method has been removed or replaced in QGIS 3, I recommend intense study of https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html (https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_Composer) and in this special case https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html and https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html

Comment: Hi,Thanks for all this links. In another forum, somone tell me about another plug-in like mine: Maps printer. This one done what I want. Thanks again